# Which one is better?Change sprint dates or one team member is not attend sprint plans for 4 months

Tags: agile, scrum, planning, sprint

We have an agile team and nearly running 80. sprint.Our sprint  starts wednesday and finish Tuesday 10 days after.One of our team member,developer, will attend to a university course every Wednesday during 4 months.Which one is better should we take sprint days Tuesday to Monday,total sprint day will not change still 10,or one member will not attend to sprint plans and team will give commitment for her.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend changing sprint ceremony day if feasible. The team member in question will only have to catch up on a day's work of the rest of the team instead of catching up on the whole user story discussion and explanation, retrospective, task decomposition, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot commit for someone else.

So check with the customer. It will probably have an impact on other planned meetings (sprint review, retrospective, ...) and if it is OK with him, change the day. Explain why you want to change the day. It is always better to have the entire team on board for the planning meeting.